# Issue with 2 digit numbers being greater than 3 digit numbers in VBA

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba

I'm running into a weird issue while building out a VBA program. The program takes in a CSV file and does some reformatting before it spits it back out. I'm running into issues with the program thinking that two digit numbers are larger than 3 digit numbers. For example it thinks that 60 is greater than 120, but recognizes that 60 is less than 80, and that 100 is less than 120. Below is my code snippet:

```
if Rate < Miles and (Miles > 60 and Miles <=80) then
   Rate = 80
elseif Rate < Miles and (Miles > 80 and Miles <=120) then
   Rate = 120
End if
```

My file is a a CSV set up like this:

```
90210,90201,60,61
90201,90210,60,100
```

In the CSV file the last two numbers in each row are what I'm focusing on. The 60s being Rate and 61 and 100 being Miles. When I run this program it will go through the first line and change Rate from 60 to 80, which is correct. The issue is when it runs the second line it leaves the 60 as 60 rather than changing it to 120.

I put a break point on on this section of code, and the variables are reading correctly, Rate is equaling 60 while Miles is equaling 100, but it skips over the `Rate = 120` portion. As a test I changed `Rate < Miles` to `Rate > Miles`, and sure enough it read the `rate = 120` line as it now believes 60 is less than 100. Of course, making this change resulted in other issues when running 3 digit Rates, therefore not a good overall solution. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are compared as strings, not as numbers.

```
"100" < "120" < "60" < "80"
```

How did you declare and assign your variables?

If you didn't declare them, they are Variants and can be either string or number. `Dim` them as `Long`.

And put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module. 
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. 
This is really a must have for VBA development.